# Find substring in file

Tags: 14.04, text-processing, find

I have a file with text like following:

> {name: "Jon", kids: [{i: 1, n: "tyrell"}, {i: 2, n: "angela"}, {i: 3, n: "elliot"}]

what I want to achieve is delete every string with ":i" so in this case it would look like this

> {name: "Jon", kids: [{n: "tyrell"}, {n: "angela"}, {n: "elliot"}]

so if there is a "i:" it should delete everything (including the i:) up to the comma ","

How could I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file
{name: "Jon", kids: [{i: 1, n: "tyrell"}, {i: 2, n: "angela"}, {i: 3, n: "elliot"}]
```

then

```
$ sed 's/i:[^,]*, //g' file
{name: "Jon", kids: [{n: "tyrell"}, {n: "angela"}, {n: "elliot"}]
```

Add `-i` or `--in-place` to overwrite the contents of the original file

---

**However** if your file contains structured data you should use the right tools for the job - yours looks *almost* like JSON aside from the unquoted keys and missing terminating brace:

```
$ jq -c --null-input '
    {name: "Jon", kids: [{i: 1, n: "tyrell"}, {i: 2, n: "angela"}, {i: 3, n: "elliot"}]} | 
  del(.kids[].i)'
{"name":"Jon","kids":[{"n":"tyrell"},{"n":"angela"},{"n":"elliot"}]}
```

Comment: Plus one. @OcK, fix the process that produces this text so that it's valid JSON, and use a proper JSON parser to handle it. This question belongs in the "don't use regex to parse html/xml/json/csv" category

Comment: Yes you are right it is a JSON file, thanks for the second approach clean and simple!

Comment: @steeldriver is there also a possibility to delete an object of the kids array if it contains a key called "z"?

Comment: @OcK that would be something like `del(.kids[] | select(has("z")))` I think - but I am a `jq` novice, really if you have `jq` specific questions they belong elsewhere

Comment: @steeldriver you my friend are not a novice you are an expert!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This one does what you ask for,

```
<<< '{name: "Jon", kids: [{i: 1, n: "tyrell"}, {i: 2, n: "angela"}, {i: 3, n: "elliot"}]' sed 's/i: .,//g'
```

This one does what you show (removes the space after the comma),

```
<<< '{name: "Jon", kids: [{i: 1, n: "tyrell"}, {i: 2, n: "angela"}, {i: 3, n: "elliot"}]' sed 's/i: ., //g'
```

What you want in the real case is to run `sed` with an input file

```
sed 's/i: ., //g' file.in
```

and probably redirect to an output file

```
sed 's/i: ., //g' file.in > file.out
```